# Disable more than one button with a click

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 answer buttons that trigger a tick or a cross to be displayed depending on whether the answer is right or not ("showDiv01"/"showDiv02"), I want to disable all of the buttons after any of them are clicked, so far I can only disable the button that is clicked  with "onClick=this.disabled = 'true';".

```
<button id="none" onClick="showDiv01(); this.disabled = 'true';">Almond White</button><br>
<button id="score" onClick="showDiv02(); this.disabled = 'true';">Raspberry Diva</button<br>
<button id="none" onClick="showDiv01(); this.disabled = 'true';">Melon Sorbet</button><br>
<button id="none" onClick="showDiv01(); this.disabled = 'true';">Gentle Lavender</button><br>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: elements cant share ID's btw

Comment: You have to select the buttons to be disabled using javascript. Come back to ask questions once you know a bit of javascript.

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: @InGodITrust Sorry, I just had "none" there as placeholder, thanks.

Comment: @MariaWarnes no problem, was just pointing out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend adding a common class to your buttons (for this example, say you `btnClass` as your class), also, you can use the same function for each button click, no need to create unique functions for buttons doing the same type of behavior:

```
function showDiv(el) {
    //"el" should be "this" passed in to the func
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btnClass");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].disabled = true;
    }
}

<button id="none" onClick="showDiv(this)"></button>
```

With `this` passed in, you have direct access to the element being clicked through the `el` param in the function. So `el.id` will result in the ID of the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

You have `showDiv01();` function called on click also. Put there code to disable buttons finding them by id.

Besides I don't think you can have same id for different buttons like "none", I would also consider keeping answer somewhere else than button id.
I would pass some parameter to `showDiv01();` function like  `showAnswerDiv(1);` or  `showAnswerDiv(2);`.

This way you could take action based on parameter which is a lot better than making function for valid or invalid answer and pinning it to button.